# REST with S/4HANA Cloud SDK: Tomee archetype project returns 403 forbidden on POST/PUT/DELETE

Tags: rest, sap-cloud-sdk

I created a S4SDK project with

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.sap.cloud.s4hana.archetypes \
  -DarchetypeArtifactId=scp-cf-tomee -DarchetypeVersion=LATEST
```

and I modified the `HelloWorldServlet` to have a `doPost` method, but I cannot get a POST request to reach it at all. I always get responses

> HTTP status 403 forbidden

How can I use the S/4HANA Cloud SDK tomee archetype for REST development?

Comment: If the provided answer was helpful would you mind accepting it? Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

If you look into the response headers of your failed request, you will likely see a header `X-CSRF-Token: Required`. A CSRF token secures your application users from becoming victims of attacks that execute unwanted actions in your application.

Therefore, any state changing operation, such as `PUT` and `POST`, requires a valid CSRF token to ensure that the action is really intended by the authenticated user who invokes it. The CSRF token can be fetched as part of any previous side-effect free request, such as `GET`. Just append the header `X-CSRF-Token: fetch` to your request and extract the returned value from the response header `X-CSRF-Token: abc123`. Finally, make sure to send the extracted value as `X-CSRF-Token: abc123` header of the next modifying request. Then everything should work as expected.

For more information, you can consult:
http://www2.hu-berlin.de/newlogic/docs/config/filter.html#CSRF_Prevention_Filter_for_REST_APIs/Basic_configuration_sample

Comment: I developed the application and trying to test in postman. First, I fetched the csrf-token using a GET request and used the resulted token in POST request. But It gave an error ** 405 Method Not Allowed**. Can you please help me?

Comment: Would you mind creating a new question for this? Kindly also share your code and a detailed description of what you are doing.

Comment: I created a new question. please follow the link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49858668/post-operation-is-failing-with-an-error-405-method-not-allowed

Answer (score 0):

The default security configuration of S4SDK contains a cross-site request forgery (CSRF) prevention filter - comment it to make REST API development straightforward - but be aware of the [CSRF problem](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)) and [how CSRF relates to cookies](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/166724/should-i-use-csrf-protection-on-rest-api-endpoints) - essentially ensure that no cookies are used in your REST application before and after adding these comments:

```
<!-- disabled to make REST work - AUTHN/AUTHZ MUST NOT USE COOKIES!
<filter>
    <filter-name>RestCsrfPreventionFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.RestCsrfPreventionFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>RestCsrfPreventionFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
-->
```

Comment: I don't think this answer is a good recommendation when deploying applications on SAP Cloud Platform. Cloud Platform uses session cookies in both environments: Neo, CloudFoundry. Even though the latter is based on Json Web Token, the AppRouter is a stateful service with respective to sessions, hence, CSRF protection is a must. Instead, securing the cookie via additional configuration in web.xml should be applied: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SecureFlag.

Comment: In addition, in the CloudFoundry environment when an AppRouter is present, you may uncomment it, because then the AppRouter does the CSRF Protection already to the client. For the backend microservices,  signed JWTs are used for authentication and authorization. Therefore, there is no need to do an additional CSRF protection on backing microservices.